# SSRS 2016 - Add As Favorite

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Attempting to tidy up the mess that is our SQL Reporting Services. While I am sorting permissions there are some reports that users would like access to that I don't wish to provide them full access to the folder said reports reside in.

You can add a report as a favorite if you can see it in the 'Report Manager' however since the report(s) in question people only have the hyperlink to because they don't have permission to enter the folders is there anyway I can add an 'Add To Favourites' Button within the report?

Or is there another method that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can create a `Linked Report` which can then be placed into another folder that they can access already. Then, they have access to the copy of the report that is created which is `linked` to a separate folder so they never have access to the folder you want to keep private.

You just click on the arrow next to the report on `report centre` and click `create linked report`.

Here is a simple guide:
https://www.tutorialgateway.org/linked-reports-in-ssrs/